# Running python in python block by block capturing the output

Tags: python, subprocess

As a pet project, I want to build something similar to the Jupyter notebook. Given an array of strings, each of which is a peace of python code, I would like to run each piece one by one in a single python process and then associate blocks of output with each piece of code. I would also like to manage it all in another (parent) python process.

To make the problem tangible, let's say I have a list of strings, each is a piece of python code. One string use variables from the preceding piece of code, i.e. they should all be run in a single process. Now I want to run one piece of code, wait until it finishes, capture the output, then run the next piece, and so on.

Unfortunately, googling around only gave me an example, where I can run peace of code, `using subprocess.Popen('python', stdout=PIPE, ...)`, but with this approach, it will start executing my command after I close stdin, effectively closing the whole python process.

Comment: What is the point of isolating each line to a separate process if you also want the processes to be able to "share" variables?

Comment: How about simply executing each string sequentially with `eval(...)`? If required, in a single subprocess?

Comment: @jordanm, I don't really want to isolate every piece, I just want to know what output one piece gives and what output I get from another. I.e. I want to associate blocks of output with each piece of code.

Comment: @Seb, I didn't think about `eval(...)` honestly, but how can I capture output of eval?

Comment: I think I missed important point, that I want to associate blocks of output with each block of code. Added that to the question.

Comment: In the extreme form, you are asking for sandboxing which is very hard to do. What *exactly* are your requirements? For example, you could replace ``sys.stdout`` etc with an IO buffer, but in an naive implementation your payload code could re-replace this again.

Comment: In simple form, I want to take pieces of code form a document, where code is marked as such, run those pieces and add output to back to the text file below the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) from the standard library to capture the output of `exec()` calls. With that, your idea of code blocks (as I understand them) is straightforward to implement:

```py
import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

class Block:
    def __init__(self, code=''):
        self.code = code
        self.stdout = io.StringIO()

    def run(self):
        with redirect_stdout(self.stdout):
            exec(self.code, globals()) # Pass global variable dict to allow modification

    @property
    def output(self):
        return self.stdout.getvalue()
```

```py
>>> b1 = Block('a = 42; print(a)')
>>> b2 = Block('print(1/a)')
>>> b1.run()
>>> b2.run()
>>> b1.output
'42\n'
>>> b2.output
'0.023809523809523808\n'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the direction where I wanted someone to guide me. Together with `multiprocessing` it solves the problem nicely!